# How do I find the SVN repository URL?

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn

I am a bit confuses finding the SVN URL to check out a copy on my computer.

The way I get to my website is: `http://dev.website.com/`

I have set up SVN here: `/home/svn/trunk`

And I checkout a copy here: `/var/www/trunk`

Sso `http://dev.website.com/` points to `/var/www/trunk`.

But I need to checkout a copy of the trunk on my computer. And I try to go to `http://dev.website.com/` or `http://svn.dev.website.com/`, but it doesn't work.

What is the URL that gets me the files from the `trunk`? Where do I need to set that link up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **not "guess and try"**, but find the location of your repository in file `httpd.conf`.

In order to do it, read the Apache configuration, and find the `DAV svn` string in it. Location container, which has this string, location parameter will have the path, used as repository path in case of a single repository or base-path for multi-repository.

**Example**

For host http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088 with configuration (part of)

```
<Location /svn/>
  DAV svn

  SVNListParentPath on
  SVNParentPath physical-path
```

path to any repository, created under SVNParentPath directory, will be

> mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Repo-dir-name/